# Получение данных с проблемного XML

Tags: php, xml

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема в получении некоторых данных с XML. С XML в плане PHP ещё не работал, только с JSON. Попробовал сперва XML->JSON, но получилась каша.

В общем, имеем следующий объект:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [id] => 2162624
    [inv] => 0
    [amount] => 0.00
    [type_curr] => WMZ
    [sign] => 5cdd60c2316994c120fea6
    [email] => тест 1
    [options] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [option] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 15885
                            [type] => text
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Из него нужно получить [type] => text. 
Но мне удалось добраться только до option, далее там в названии массив(?):

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15885
            [type] => text
        )

)
```

И вытянуть не получается. Сам код(в первой строке сам XML-запрос):

```
$xml = '<request><id>2162624</id><inv>0</inv><amount>0.00</amount><type_curr>WMZ</type_curr><sign>5cdd60c2316994c120fea6</sign><email>тест 1</email><options><option id="15885" type="text"><![CDATA[тест 15885]]></option></options></request>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

print_r($xml->options->option);
```

В чём проблема, и что там делает массив? Можно ли как-то вытащить нужные мне данные?

P.S. Структуру XML сменить не могу, получаю её с сервиса, тут лишь "пример" на основе одного из запросов.

Comment: Чисто мысли в слух. Если вы можете получить этот xml файл вручную, то сможете открыть через текстовый редактор и выяснить какие в нем постоянные ошибки. Потом можете в PHP получать этот xml, например функцией file_get_contents исправлять в нем те самые ошибки и сохранить его. А потом уже получаете с этого исправленного xml нужные вам данные.

Answer (score 2):

Если бы xml был бы не валидным, то `simplexml_load_string` вернул бы **false**
Вам нужно достать [атрибуты](http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) объекта:

```
$attributes = $xml->options->option->attributes();
echo (string)$attributes['id'];
echo (string)$attributes['type'];
```

или

```
$type = (string)$xml->options->option->attributes()->type;
echo $type;
```